# Default Css overrides all new classes/div

Tags: html, css

I have Wordpress site where my theme use the following width,magin and position on all pages.
This is the default css and like it however if I create a new class/divand dont wont use the default css that is being used by eveything else how could i overwrite it for a specific class/div tag.

Standard css:

```
.tg-container
{
width:1200px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}
```

So this div will center all content on the site

So in my newly created class I dont want to .tg-container to overwrite my css.
With my class I want to use full width and not center it.

My class css

```
.wc-block-grid__products
{dont use css from .tg-container}
```

Looking forward for help regarding it!

Best Regards,
Martin

Comment: either parent of class or some element inside class is using that class, inspecting with chrome dev tools would be best option , one way to test , specify that class with some dummy values to verify like .tg-container( color: 'red' }

Comment: Hi, Yes .tg-container is the container of all div and classes created however i dont want to remove that class

Comment: `.tg-container { width: unset; margin: unset; position: unset; }`

Comment: @connexo .tg-container .wc-block-grid__products  { width: unset !important; margin: unset!important; position: unset !important; } does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with your class make sure you have to override those three properties with your desired values this class in your Html

```
.wc-block-grid__products {
  width: //your desired width you want;
  margin: //your desired margin you want;
  position: //your desired postion you want;
}
```

Comment: It does still not work... .tg-container will still ovveride my css values for .wc-block-grid__products

Comment: @Batistuta Can you use fiddle to demonstrate your issue that will help to understand